# Node-gyp cannot compile a nodejs extension ('fatal error, thread' file not found)

Tags: c++, node.js, gcc, node-gyp

I have this node extension made by a colleague and I'm trying to compile it through `node-gyp configure` (everything alright) and then `node-gyp build` (`fatal error, 'thread' file not found`). Now, I believe this is a problem of gcc, and I read somewhere that I need as flag `-stdlib=libc+++`. My `binding.gyp` file looks like this:

```
{
    "targets": [
    {
        "target_name": "overcpu",
        "sources": [ "overcpu.cpp" ],
        "cflags" : [ "-stdlib=libc++" ]
    }
    ]
}
```

But I still get the error. I installed XCode and the developer tools, moreover not satisfied I installed `gcc` through `brew`. Unfortunately I keep receiving the same error.
By doing `gcc -v` I get the following output:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Is there something wrong with my `gcc`, or is it `node-gyp` (v1.0.1) which is driving me crazy?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you do `node-gyp --loglevel=silly rebuild` in the addon's directory, do you see the `cflags` being set on the command line during compilation/linking?

Comment: Hi, there is a *lot* of logs, but I cannot see `cflags` being set anywhere. Can you hint me where this is happening? Maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to also add `-std=c++11` to your `cflags` argument list in order to fully activate C++11 support.

**UPDATE:** For OSX specifically (the `cflags` should work on BSD and Linux), you will need to also add a condition inside your `targets` settings like so:

```
{
    "targets": [
    {
        "target_name": "overcpu",
        "sources": [ "overcpu.cpp" ],
        "cflags" : [ "-std=c++1", "-stdlib=libc++" ],
        "conditions": [
          [ 'OS!="win"', {
            "cflags+": [ "-std=c++11" ],
            "cflags_c+": [ "-std=c++11" ],
            "cflags_cc+": [ "-std=c++11" ],
          }],
          [ 'OS=="mac"', {
            "xcode_settings": {
              "OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS" : [ "-std=c++11", "-stdlib=libc++" ],
              "OTHER_LDFLAGS": [ "-stdlib=libc++" ],
              "MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET": "10.7"
            },
          }],
        ],
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for modifying the answer. Now the thread error seems to be gone, but I get `fatal error: 'linux/unistd.h' file not found`. I guess some flag is missing again?

Comment: That sounds like the code may not be cross-platform? Anyway, you should be ok by changing `linux/unistd.h` in your code to just `unistd.h`.

Comment: So the compilation said there was a problem with __NR_gettid, which I defined outside. When defining it (`#if defined(OS_MACOSX)` bla bla `#endif`) the compilation worked but then calling the extension from node gives a "bad system call: 12" error. :-(

Comment: Maybe I need another flag to define the missing variable?

Comment: There is no `gettid` on OSX, so if you have code that requires it, you'll have to either find if OSX has something comparable or otherwise rewrite that portion of the code in a cross-platform way.