# error: ‘std::enable_if_t’ has not been declared

Tags: c++

Currently, I am having issue with this line of code. Its showing this error message `error: ‘std::enable_if_t’ has not been declared`. I have included the `#include <type_traits>` header file but its still the same. Below is my src code:

```
template<class T>
std::string toJSON(const T& o,std::enable_if_t<detail::hasBindFunction<T>::value>* =nullptr)
```

I have added the c++ version into my binding.gyp file. `"cflags": [ "-std=c++14" ],`. Still the error shows there.

Can I know how to fix this error.

Comment: You need to enable `c++14`

Comment: Explain what is the binding.gyp. Is it in an IDE?

Comment: I don't know about binding.gyp, but I guess it should have `cxxflags`. I believe that `cflags` is used for C instead

Comment: its something like a makefile where nodejs requires

Comment: @Danh i have try it.. its still the same..

Comment: node-gyp will generate a Makefile, can you post the result Makefile or part of it which has CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS

Comment: I cant post it here, because of the length of the Makefile is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25645883/4498831)

```
{
    "targets": [
    {
        "target_name": "yourproject",
        "sources": [ "yourproject.cpp" ],
        "cflags" : [ "-std=c++14", "-stdlib=libc++" ]
        "conditions": [
          [ 'OS!="win"', {
            "cflags+": [ "-std=c++14" ],
            "cflags_c+": [ "-std=c++14" ],
            "cflags_cc+": [ "-std=c++14" ],
          }],
          [ 'OS=="mac"', {
            "xcode_settings": {
              "OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS" : [ "-std=c++14", "-stdlib=libc++" ],
              "OTHER_LDFLAGS": [ "-stdlib=libc++" ],
              "MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET": "10.7"
            },
          }],
        ],
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what if its linux

Comment: It uses the config in `'OS!="win"'`. Do you mean “what if it is Windows”?

Answer (score 6):

`std::enable_if_t` is a C++14 feature, so you need to enable C++14 in your compiler. In Clang or GCC this is accomplished with the `-std=c++14` flag.

Comment: I have added the ` "cflags": [ "-std=c++14" ],` into the binding.gyp file but still its the same error.